# How do I create a folder in VBScript? I get an error

Tags: vbscript, directory

I'm trying to create a folder in the directory below and am getting an error saying bad number or name? I have only just started VBScript and need help.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim Shell
Dim ObjFSO

Set Shell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ObjFSO =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'creates a folder in the path'

ObjFSO.CreateFolder """C:\Program Files\MECracker\"""
```

Comment: i have done that and it seems to have worked howver a new error says that i dont have permission is there anyway to grant permission?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose four of your six double quotation marks.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim Shell
Dim ObjFSO

Set Shell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ObjFSO =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'creates a folder in the path'

ObjFSO.CreateFolder "C:\Program Files\MECracker\"
```